# Gap between left drawable and text in a EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hello I am setting drawable to left end in the `EditText` using property `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_drawable"`, I am trying this it set the drawable perfectly but it is not setting gap between left drawable and text. Could you please help me to achieve this ?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_edittext_vertical_top_margin"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_drawable"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: Use this properties android:drawablePadding=""

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You should add `android:drawablePadding` attribute to your `EditText`. Example layout with `10dp` drawable padding:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_edittext_vertical_top_margin"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_drawable"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: I want to set padding right of drawable not complete side

Comment: `android:drawablePadding` sets right padding in this case.

Comment: yes I tried `android:drawablePadding` but it set the padding to left,right,top,bottom but I want only to right side

Comment: Try to add `android:padding="0dp"`.

Comment: I just tried `android:drawablePadding` in my project and it sets only right padding.

Comment: @erakitin i want to align the drawableLeft and the hint text. Is it Possible ??

Answer (score 5):

to move the drawable icon left or right use `android:paddingLeft`  or `android:paddingRight` do not use `android:drawablePadding`

Answer (score 2):

When you set any drawable using `android:drawableLeft` / `android:drawableRight` property then you can add space or gap using `android:drawablePadding` property.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_edittext_vertical_top_margin"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_drawable"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp" // set your padding or gap size here
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```